# WinUI3: Unable to access UIElement defined programmatically inside a event delegate function

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winui-3

I'm creating the UI in WinUI3 with C++ programmatically.

In XAML we can access an UIElement from all event delegate functions by its [x:Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-name-attribute) property, but when I define everything programmatically in c++ I was not able to set something like that.

I want to make the UIElements defined programmatically accessible from Event delegate functions. I tried it accessing directly(like the below code) but was not able to achieve that.

This is my Mainwindow file

```
namespace winrt::TestWinUI::implementation
{
struct MainWindow: MainWindowT<MainWindow>
{
    MainWindow();

    int32_t MyProperty();
    void MyProperty(int32_t value);

    void ComboxSelectionChanged(IInspectable const& sender, RoutedEventArgs const& args);

    Window      window;
    StackPanel  line;
    ComboBox combobox1;
    ComboBox combobox2;
}
```

MainWindow constructor

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(){
    combobox1.PlaceholderText(L"Select Country");
    combobox1.Items().Append(box_value(L"India"));
    combobox1.SelectionChanged({ this,&MainWindow::ComboxSelectionChanged });

    line.Children().Append(combobox1);

    window.Content(line);
    window.Activate();
}
```

This is my App file

```
void App::OnLaunched(Microsoft::UI::Xaml::LaunchActivatedEventArgs const&)
{
make<MainWindow>();
}
```

Here I was able to access all the UIElements[like combobox1] of MainWindow in MainWindow() constructor and was able to get the screen programmatically.

I have assigned the ComboxSelectionChanged event to combobox1 when item selection is changed.

By this, I was able to get an event when the item selection was changed in combobox1. But when I tried to access combobox2 inside the ComboxSelectionChanged() event delegate function,

[image]

I'm getting a runtime error like this

[image]

It would be of great help if you could help me with accessing the UIElement from all event delegate functions when UIElements are defined programmatically.

Comment: You shouldn't detail/link to your issue in another site. If you need help from people here on SO, you should include all details in your question here on SO.

Comment: Is combobox2 initialized and added to the visual tree?

Comment: @Nick In the above example, No. But I tried accessing the UIElement which is already been set before and added to the tree. Got the same behavior as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

The issue was because of App.xaml.cpp file.

```
void App::OnLaunched(Microsoft::UI::Xaml::LaunchActivatedEventArgs const&)
{
make<MainWindow>();
}
```

I was getting the crash in this case, I was not able to access UIElement defined programmatically inside an event delegate function, because the window is initialized with null in .h : winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window window{ nullptr };

```
void App::OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs const&)
{
window = make<MainWindow>();
window.Activate();
}
```

But 2 windows will be created as I'm creating one programmatically and activating it and the window created programmatically was able to access UIElement defined programmatically inside an event delegate function

So to make the windows which were created programmatically as the single main window, and not to use MainWindow.xaml, we can directly initialize App.xaml.h's window to the window which was programatically created. instead of calling

```
make<MainWindow>();
```

This will solve the issue.

Thank you